# Rails won't output data in json

Tags: javascript, json, ruby-on-rails-3

This drives me crazy

I need links to be in a format of

```
links = [{source: 1, target: 2}, {..}, ...]
```

controller code:

```
  @edges = []
     Follow.where("followable_type= 'User'").map do |x|
      @edges << {source: x.follower_id, target: x.followable_id}
     end
```

View code (inside javascript):

```
var links = [(<%= @edges.to_json %>)];
```

output in html source is

```
var links = [([{&quot;source&quot;:2,&quot;target&quot;:3},{&quot;source&quot;:2,&quot;target&quot;:1},{&quot;source&quot;:8,&quot;target&quot;:1},{&quot;source&quot;:1,&quot;target&quot;:8},{&quot;source&quot;:17,&quot;target&quot;:13},{&quot;source&quot;:8,&quot;target&quot;:13},{&quot;source&quot;:8,&quot;target&quot;:3},{&quot;source&quot;:13,&quot;target&quot;:3},{&quot;source&quot;:3,&quot;target&quot;:2},{&quot;source&quot;:39,&quot;target&quot;:13},{&quot;source&quot;:3,&quot;target&quot;:39},{&quot;source&quot;:15,&quot;target&quot;:1},{&quot;source&quot;:1,&quot;target&quot;:15},{&quot;source&quot;:3,&quot;target&quot;:1},{&quot;source&quot;:3,&quot;target&quot;:8},{&quot;source&quot;:3,&quot;target&quot;:13},{&quot;source&quot;:21,&quot;target&quot;:3},{&quot;source&quot;:13,&quot;target&quot;:21},{&quot;source&quot;:13,&quot;target&quot;:39},{&quot;source&quot;:21,&quot;target&quot;:13},{&quot;source&quot;:21,&quot;target&quot;:27},{&quot;source&quot;:27,&quot;target&quot;:13},{&quot;source&quot;:1,&quot;target&quot;:3},{&quot;source&quot;:1,&quot;target&quot;:39},{&quot;source&quot;:1,&quot;target&quot;:2},{&quot;source&quot;:1,&quot;target&quot;:13},{&quot;source&quot;:1,&quot;target&quot;:21},{&quot;source&quot;:1,&quot;target&quot;:27}])];
```

so I thought I should put in html_safe in there.. that gives

```
var links = [([{"source":2,"target":3},{"source":2,"target":1},{"source":8,"target":1},{"source":1,"target":8},{"source":17,"target":13},{"source":8,"target":13},{"source":8,"target":3},{"source":13,"target":3},{"source":3,"target":2},{"source":39,"target":13},{"source":3,"target":39},{"source":15,"target":1},{"source":1,"target":15},{"source":3,"target":1},{"source":3,"target":8},{"source":3,"target":13},{"source":21,"target":3},{"source":13,"target":21},{"source":13,"target":39},{"source":21,"target":13},{"source":21,"target":27},{"source":27,"target":13},{"source":1,"target":3},{"source":1,"target":39},{"source":1,"target":2},{"source":1,"target":13},{"source":1,"target":21},{"source":1,"target":27}])];
```

which is better, but every key is a string.. and I need it to be not string

How can I make this work? Is the problem in the controller or view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of symbol in JSON (like in Ruby). The key will have to be a string in JSON. In your case, you don't seem to need the keys. You can just have an array of follower id and followable id.